# Order Generic List <T> in certain order .NET

Tags: .net, list

i have a problem to order a list by certain rule.

Actually i have Links Object List For Example List list ;

Links Class it's build in this way :

```
private class Links
 { 
            public Int32 IdHost { get; set; }
            public String Url { get; set; }
 }
```

Now using this Code i order the list by IdHost.

```
var listSortedById = source
                     .OrderBy(n => n.IdHost).ToList();
```

The problem now starting cause i wish that idHost == 2 should be put every 5 element in the list instead one each other.

**Update Example**

For Example : 2 1 1 1 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 4 4 4 i mean put idHost == 2 every 5 elements.

For what concern the element which comes first i would like that it shold be the idHost == 2. 
Is there a way to do this with Linq?

Comment: how should the other elements be sorted? if you order by ID it would be 211112333324444... and not like you specified. So like I understand it every Id can exist more than once. How do you decide which of the same Ids comes first? We need more detail. Maybe an explanation on what you want to achieve would help also

Comment: yes you understand right , i wrong to write example :D should be like 211112333324444. I update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it so hard on yourself. If you think too hard you'll reach for really fancy complicated solutions that use LINQ in non-intuitive ways. Instead, KISS.

First, sort the items that don't have `IdHost == 2` and put those items into a list:

```
var sorted = source.Where(x => x.IdHost != 2)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.IdHost)
                   .ToList();
```

Then, collect the items that have `IdHost == 2`:

```
var twos = source.Where(x => x.IdHost == 2);
```

Finally, insert these items every 5th position into your list:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var two in twos) {
    sorted.Insert(index, two);
    index += 5;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right :) I was looking for a complicated solution. By the way i think that should be sort.Insert instead of Add. Thanks!